# How to use pact scenario state with wiremock-pact-generator library

Tags: java, junit5, wiremock, pact

We are trying to create a pact contract file with wiremock-pact-generator by following the [reference](https://github.com/Arsenalist/pact-junit5-wiremock-spring-example):  How ever we could not able to find scenario state handled in the library (wiremock-pact-generator).

Since we are able to provide a state with pactdslwithprovider library, the same thing we are trying to achieve with wiremock-pact-generator library. But we couldn't able to find the way how to provide the state.

Could you please let us know, if we are missing some thing here?

Added the wiremock-pact-generation listener to mockserver.
`

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setup() {
  mockServer =
      new WireMockServer(options().port(1080).extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true)));
  mockServer.addMockServiceRequestListener(
      WireMockPactGenerator.builder("product-service-consumer", "producte-service-provider").build());
  mockServer.start();
}
```

`

Wiremock stub:

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPathPattern" : "/products/1001",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{\"productId\":1001,\"name\": \"Dell Laptop\",\"description\": \"Warranty expiring soon\"}",
    "headers" : {
      "X-Application-Context" : "application:-1",
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    },
    "transformers" : [ "response-template" ]

  }
}
```

Pact Generated file:

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "product-service-consumer"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "product-service-provider"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "GET /products/1001 -> 200",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/products/1001",
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "accept-encoding": "gzip",
          "accept": "*/*",
          "user-agent": "ReactorNetty/1.0.24"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "x-application-context": "application:-1"
        },
        "body": {
          "productId": 1001,
          "name": "Dell Laptop",
          "description": "Warranty expiring soon"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to make sure the scenario state should be added in pact contract generation file:
In this case : "provider_state": "Fetch Product for Id 1001" should be in interactions.

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "product-service-consumer"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "product-service-provider"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
     

    *"provider_state": "Fetch Product for Id 1001",*

      "description": "GET /products/1001 -> 200",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/products/1001",
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "accept-encoding": "gzip",
          "accept": "*/*",
          "user-agent": "ReactorNetty/1.0.24"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "x-application-context": "application:-1"
        },
        "body": {
          "productId": 1001,
          "name": "Dell Laptop",
          "description": "Warranty expiring soon"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have similar requirements, out of interest what solution you went for in the end? Do you mind posting an answer if you have time, please?

Answer (score 1):

The Pact Wiremock library doesn't have support for setting provider states.

What are you trying to achieve by using them? It's really not intended for use with Pact verification, but for use in other cases (such as swagger mock validator or Pactflow's bi-directional contract testing feature, which doesn't need states).

Comment: We are trying to use existing wiremock stubs to generate a pactfile (instead of writing new tests using the pact dsl), and expecting that the providers would also be able to verify the pactfile like the same way.
PS: Gurubabu and I work together, and we are in Melbourne :-), We met as well @Matthew Fellows

Comment: Wiremock does have concept of state management too, I don't see a good reason why it cann't be supported by the library. On the provider side, we are using the pact-jvm annotations to implement the verification using the state, so that the generated pactfile interactions can be verified.

Comment: Nice to hear from you Kiran! :) 

So, I'm sure the maintainers of that library would consider a PR to add state management if you're up for it, but note that it still doesn't have the concept of Pact Matchers, so it only solves part of the provider side pain point. Something for you to consider in any case.

Comment: Matt, I just went through one your pactflow video article on Youtube, there you are using wiremock pact generator library to create pact contract file. Is that fine if we create contract without Pact Matchers and States?

Video article I referred: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lf_d0XvNRs

Comment: It's fine, as long as you are using PactFlow's bi-directional contract testing capability. It's not recommended to use that library with a Pact verification on the backend, because without the matches etc. the tests will be quite brittle.